# My Blazor Server App hits a null reference error on Azure B2c login on one local machine but not on another local machine, any ideas?

Tags: c#, azure, blazor, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side

For some reason, my Blazor App works totally fine on my laptop, but not on my Desktop PC when I cloned the GitHub Repo. I repaired the install of visual studio 2019 and restarted my machine and it didn't fix it. I also have the web app deployed on Azure, and it doesn't hit this null reference error. I'm not sure if it's related, but I use Azure B2C for user credentials, and the error will hit after I sign in and it's redirecting back to my site. Below is where the error hits in my _Host.cshtml file.

`<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />`

I'm kind of out of ideas for this, so I'd appreciate any input, thanks!

link to my github repo https://github.com/Zami77/wargamer_showcase

Comment: is the appsettings.json file loading correctly on your desktop? also is the localhort:portnumber the same as your laptops

Comment: @AndrewE localhost port is the same and I believe appsettings.json is loading fine. It still connects to my CosmosDB, which the endpoint is in my appsettings.

Comment: when say you have cloned the repo, are there any files that might have been ignored?

Comment: I git ignore appsettings, bin, and obj directories. Appsettings isn't an issue as I have that there. Not sure on bin and obj, but I'm fairly certain I looked that up and it "shouldn't" be an issue.

Comment: after you have logged in, is there any errors in the Output?

Comment: It won't even load the index after I sign in, it just crashes the app with the null reference exception. I can even try re-building and running the app again and it will still hit that null reference exception. It's very strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238925/discussion-between-zami77-and-andrewe).

Comment: I have the same error on my project. Don't know if it works elsewhere besides my machine

Comment: @Emmanouil Uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling and Reinstalling Visual studio 2019 Community fixed the issue!